# hide() doesn work in td with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpreU.png)

```
$("#table_th_id_rdv_cm_presta").hide(); //<th>
$(".table_class_rdv_cm_presta").hide(); //<td>
```

when I click on the filter button the th disappears but the TD no...
but if I reclick on the button, it works as it should.

thank you in advance

Comment: It's LOL. with two line of code we couldn't solve your problem.Add more data like HTML +JQUERY full code

Comment: One selector is id based, the other is css class based. Is `table_class_rdv_cm_presta` applied to the `<td class="table_class_rdv_cm_presta">`?

Comment: We are going to need a lot more detail here.  Using an image as you have is insufficient.

Comment: pls provide table

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#event_non_valide_DM',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
        $("#table_th_num_site").hide();
        $("#table_th_id_rdv_cm_presta").show();
        $("#table_th_mois").show();
        $("#table_th_vol_communique").show();
        $("#table_th_borne_antivol").show();
        $(".table_class_id_niveau_4").hide();
        $(".table_class_rdv_cm_presta").show();
        $(".table_class_mois").show();
        $(".table_class_vol_comminique").show();
        $(".table_class_borne_antivol").show();

    });

Comment: @ElmahdiTamika Edit that into the question, please.

Comment: pls provide your table and jquery code, so we can solve

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the working example,

Html code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th id="table_th_id_rdv_cm_presta">Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td class="table_class_rdv_cm_presta">Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td  class="table_class_rdv_cm_presta">Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td  class="table_class_rdv_cm_presta">Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

let if you hide contact column in table on click contact button

```
<button id="contact">Contact</button>
```

Here is jquery code the hide contact column

```
$(function(){
$('#country').click(function(event) {
$('table #table_th_id_rdv_cm_presta, .table_class_rdv_cm_presta').hide();
});
```